# How to download file with UTF-8 file name in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, utf-8

I want download file that has UTF-8 filename, such as `یک.jpg`, in PHP.
I tested many solutions that are posted on websites but they are not working.
This is the solution I tested:

```php
$file_utf8 = iconv( "iso-8859-1", "utf-8", $file );
if (file_exists($file_utf8))
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
else
    echo($file_utf8);*/
```

and ...

Comment: So why did you specify `iso-8859-1` as an incoming encoding?

Comment: beacase it is persian encoding and my filenames have persian characters

Comment: "beacase it is persian encoding" --- are you sure? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 "and my filenames have persian characters" --- why do you think it's not in `UTF-8` originally?

Comment: not actualy persian encoding.... but contain persian chararcters..

Comment: So, the question is still in act: what encoding the original filename is? Why do you think so? An important note: having a persian character in a filename does not mean it's `iso-8859-1` or even `iso-8859-6`

Comment: private function downloadFile ($url, $path)
 {
  try{
  
  $newfname = $path;
  try{
   
   $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
  }
  catch (Exception $e){}
   if ($file) {
    $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");
    if ($newf)
    while(!feof($file)) {
      fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
    }
  }
  if ($file) {
    fclose($file);
  }
  if ($newf) {
    fclose($newf);
  }
  return(true);
  }catch(Exception $e)
  {return(false); }
 }

Comment: i test many solution .... but dont worked...